# Altering facet_grid() height only for one facet (row) is it possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-text

I'm trying to improve a simple but important detail in my facet_grid graphic.

I played with scale and space parameteres of facet_grid() function. But I would like to increase the height **only for** the bottom facet in order to be possible to read the sample count that appears cut off in the graph (highlighted in red). See Image1.
The code used is:

```
    ggplot(salm_data, aes(x=SALM) ) + geom_bar(stat = "count", position = position_dodge())
 + facet_grid(YEAR ~ TYPE, scales = "free_x", space = "free") 
 +  geom_text(size=2.5, stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), vjust = -0.3) +theme_bw() + labs(y="Number of samples") + 
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
 labs(x=expression(paste(italic("Klebsiella spp."), " ")))
```

**Image 1:**
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjvR8.jpg)

To try to overcome this "problem" I tried including next code to enlarge the Y-axis:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 300, by = 40))
```

But I'm not capable to improve the situation (see Image2).

**Image 2:**
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMoq2.jpg)

Could you help me with some ideas to overcome this scenario?

Thanks on advance for your help/comments,

Magi

Comment: The [`ggh4x::force_panelsizes()`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#panel-sizes-1) might help you finetune facet proportions. (Disclaimer: I wrote that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid graphics enable you to modify the `widths` and `heights` of `ggplot()` objects.

Sample code:

```
library(grid)   



gg = ggplot(salm_data, aes(x=type) ) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "count", position = position_dodge())+ 
      facet_grid(year ~ type, scales = "free_x", space = "free")+
      geom_text(size=2.5, stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), vjust = -0.3) +
      theme_bw() + 
      labs(y="Number of samples") + 
      theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
      labs(x=expression(paste(italic("Klebsiella spp."), " ")))
    
    
    
gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g))
gt$widths[7] = 4*gt$widths[7]  # modify panel-1-2 and panel-2-2  
gt$heights[7] = 4*gt$heights[7] #modify panel-1-2 and panel-2-2 
grid.draw(gt)
```

Sample plot:

[image]
Sample data:

```
salm_data<-structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 
2002, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 
2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 
2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-112L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks @Rfanatic. That's just the thing that I desired.

I create the gtable from package `grid` as you indicated but I have used also the library `gtable` to help me to discover the panel codification for my case. Here's the code if can also help someone in the future:

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))
gt$widths[14] = 1*gt$widths[14]    
gt$heights[14] = 4*gt$heights[14]  
grid.draw(gt)
```

I use the position 14 because it was the row position number for the square that I have problems:

```
library(gtable)
gtable_show_layout(gt)
```

But the best for me it has been print the TableGrob:

> print(gt)
> #17  1 (14-14,11-11)  panel-4-4                     gTree[panel-16.gTree.8635]

I was interested in panel-4-4 in my example (only I printed here this line of the gt output). Moreover, due to I want to change the row height and width, I pick up 14 instead of 11.

Thanks .